# Access property list

Tags: iphone, uitableview, properties

i´ve created a plist with three rows like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>intro_buttons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>button1</key>
        <string>1.1</string>
        <key>button2</key>
        <string>1.2</string>
        <key>button3</key>
        <string>1.3</string>
    </dict>
    <key>end_buttons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>button1</key>
        <string>2.1</string>
        <key>button2</key>
        <string>2.2</string>
        <key>button3</key>
        <string>2.3</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I want to fill tableview based on my plist. But i have no idea how do access each element.I´ve tested that so far, but no luck.

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[contentDict objectForKey:@"intro_buttons" ]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Could anybody point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here it is:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourpath.plist"];
    NSDictionary *plistData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];
    NSDictionary *introButtons = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[plistData objectForKey:@"intro_Buttons"]];
    NSString * button1 = [introButtons objectForKey:@"button1"];
```

Make sure you added the plist in your resources folder..